# Wildfly Login With Username And Role

Tags: wildfly

For an integration test EAR I need my Wildfly to be able to log in different users with a specific role.

- `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.SimpleServerLoginModule` doesn't allow me to specify a role
- `org.jboss.security.auth.spi.IdentityLoginModule` doesn't allow different users

So evidently I need to use something different. I tried to use a temporary database like this:

```
<login-module code="org.jboss.security.auth.spi.DatabaseServerLoginModule"
        flag="required">
    <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:/AcmeDS" />
    <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT ?" />
    <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT 'my_role', 'Roles'" />
    <module-option name="password-stacking" value="useFirstPass" />
</login-module>
```

...aaand:

```
<datasources>
    <datasource jndi-name="java:/AcmeDS" pool-name="AcmeDS" enabled="true">
    <connection-url>jdbc:h2:mem:test;DB_CLOSE_DELAY=-1</connection-url>
    <driver>h2</driver>
        <pool>
            <min-pool-size>10</min-pool-size>
            <max-pool-size>20</max-pool-size>
            <prefill>true</prefill>
        </pool>
        <security>
            <user-name>sa</user-name>
            <password>sa</password>
        </security>
    </datasource>
    <drivers>
        <driver name="h2" module="com.h2database.h2">
            <xa-datasource-class>org.h2.jdbcx.JdbcDataSource</xa-datasource-class>
        </driver>
    </drivers>
</datasources>
```

As suggested in the [JBoss tutorial](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/WFLY8/DataSource+configuration). Still I get the following exception for the clients:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: javax.security.sasl.SaslException: Authentication failed: the server presented no authentication mechanisms
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.IoFutureHelper.get(IoFutureHelper.java:92)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConnectionPool.getConnection(ConnectionPool.java:77)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.RemotingConnectionManager.getConnection(RemotingConnectionManager.java:51)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.setupEJBReceivers(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:155)
at org.jboss.ejb.client.remoting.ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.getCurrent(ConfigBasedEJBClientContextSelector.java:115)
```

5 minutes later I got (I'm not aware of any changes): `all available authentication mechanisms failed`

(It worked right until the point where I needed a role, so I guess the setup for the client side is okay.)

What did I do I wrong? How can I get the Wildfly to at least show exceptions or something so I can debug the problem? Is there a better way to get the Wilfly to acknowledge different users with a specific role?

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [Java Security Quickstart Archetype](https://github.com/karlnicholas/javaee-security-quickstart-archetype). It has Java EE Security worked out, at least at the level I think you are trying to do.

In short, you need to have a security-domain, more like so:

```
<security-domain name="jboss-security-quickstart" cache-type="default">
<authentication>
    <login-module code="Database" flag="required">
        <module-option name="dsJndiName" value="java:jboss/datasources/ExampleDS"/>
        <module-option name="principalsQuery" value="SELECT PASSWORD FROM USER WHERE EMAIL=?"/>
        <module-option name="rolesQuery" value="SELECT R.ROLE, 'Roles' FROM ROLE R INNER JOIN USER_ROLE UR ON  UR.ROLES_ID = R.ID INNER JOIN USER U ON U.ID = UR.USER_ID WHERE U.EMAIL=?"/>
        <module-option name="hashAlgorithm" value="SHA-256"/>
        <module-option name="hashEncoding" value="base64"/>
        <module-option name="hashCharset" value="utf-8"/>
        </login-module>
    </authentication>
</security-domain>
```

You need to have a jboss-web.xml in your WEB-INF directory that points to it:

```
<!DOCTYPE jboss-web>
<jboss-web xmlns="http://www.jboss.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas
    http://www.jboss.org/schema/jbossas/jboss-web_7_2.xsd">
    <!-- Configure usage of the security domain "javaee-security-quickstart" -->
    <security-domain>javaee-security-quickstart</security-domain>
    <disable-audit>true</disable-audit>
</jboss-web>
```

And a web.xml that uses it:

```
<security-constraint>
    <web-resource-collection>
    <web-resource-name>User Views</web-resource-name>
        <url-pattern>/views/user/*</url-pattern>
    </web-resource-collection>
    <auth-constraint>
        <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
        <role-name>USER</role-name>
    </auth-constraint>
</security-constraint>
<login-config>
    <auth-method>FORM</auth-method>
    <form-login-config>
        <form-login-page>/views/login.xhtml</form-login-page>
        <form-error-page>/views/login.xhtml?Retry=True</form-error-page>
    </form-login-config>
</login-config>
<security-role>
    <role-name>ADMIN</role-name>
</security-role>
<security-role>
    <role-name>USER</role-name>
</security-role>
```

These are the basics, but it's a little easier to see it in action.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't really want to have a database if possible, because that would make the setup much more complex.